# xautolock tries to log itself when already locked

Tags: linux, lock-screen, i3-window-manager, dunst

I'm using the following command after login to enable automatic locking of my screen:

```
xautolock -corners ---- -time 1 -locker "bash /path/to/i3lock.sh /path/to/Wallpaper.png" -notify 10 -notifier "notify-send i3lock 'The screen will be locked soon! Do some action to prevent.'"
```

The [`i3lock.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weilbith/scripts/master/i3lock.sh) is just about a lot of colors and texts to use, expecting the path to the wallpaper as first argument. I'm using the AUR package [i3lock-color](https://github.com/PandorasFox/i3lock-color). But colleagues observed the same problem with alternative `i3lock` packages.

This works pretty well and combined with a keybinding to `xautoloack -locknow` I was very happy.

But for a while now I'm faced with the problem that `xautolock` tries to lock again an again. Seeing already the locked screen, after the timer has run out again, the message `locking...` is shown, followed by a failed message. Also my notification daemon `dunst` seems not to recognize the locked screen anymore. So messages are shown on the lock screen, so also the notification about the soon locking screen.

So my question is how can I fix this? How to make `xautolock` and `dunst` aware of the locked screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in [this subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/b2ux20/i3lock_with_xautolock_is_bugging/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share), the problem can be solved by adding the argument `--nofork` to the `i3lock` command.